# success method not fire on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

When I ran below code for `bttn click event` it `doesn't return a data for success method.` 
But it goes for controller method and return false (boolean value) as a out put.I need to pick that boolean value from javascript code.

Why it doesn't work ?

Javascript code is as below:

```
 $('#btnClockInTime').off('click').on('click', function () {

                var isClockOutTimeCompleted = true;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Employees/IsClockOutTimeCompleted",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { employeeId: employeeId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (!data) {
                            isClockOutTimeCompleted = data;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

Controller Action Method is as below:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult IsClockOutTimeCompleted(Guid employeeId)
        {
            var clockingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today);

            var isClockOutTimeCompleted = Repository.IsClockOutTimeCompleted(employeeId, clockingDate);

            return Json(isClockOutTimeCompleted, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Repository code is as below:

```
public bool IsClockOutTimeCompleted(Guid employeeId, DateTime clockingDate)
        {
            var clockOutTime = (from c in Catalog.EmployeeClockInOutTimes
                                where (c.Employee.Id == employeeId && c.Created == clockingDate && c.ClockOut == null)
                                select c).FirstOrDefault();

            return clockOutTime == null;
        }
```

**UPDATE :**

Response is as below :

[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**

Screen 1 :

[image]

Screen 2 :

[image]

Screen 3 :

[image]

As shown above images my debug doesn't come into success method.
After 2nd screen (when debug at `error`) it goes to controller and brings data.
3rd screen shows a status after returning from controller.Any idea ?

Comment: Is it because you are not performing the request as a post?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: `if (!data)` this means the value being checked is boolean. Is `data` boolean?

Comment: @Aashray Javascript is not strictly typed like C++ or C#. That expression is valid to check for `truthy` kind of values.

Comment: @Jai no errors. Plz check my update picture.

Comment: so its checking if there are some values stored in `data`?

Comment: @Aashray yes.Check whether true or false.for my scenario it's return false as out put but that value doesn't capture success method.Any idea?

Comment: `isClockOutTimeCompleted` is a local variable of the anonymous onclick function you have created. Where are you actually trying to retrieve the value of the variable `isClockOutTimeCompleted`? Did you try alerting the value in your success callback? What did you get? And your response data type is set as `json` but your response looks like a plain string?

Comment: you aren't returning a valid JSON object. value being returned is either true or false.

Comment: @Sampath I can tell you one thing: you're original JavaScript code is correct ( both jQuery and native JSON implementation understand `false` as a string and can parse it correctly ). The `ReferenceError` is very bizarre. No matter what `data` is it cannot throw a `ReferenceError` since `data` is an argument of success callback. Or am I missing something? I don't know much about asp.net, but JavaScript looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that if you're return value is just `false` as a string then that will become your `data` value and as a result:

```
if (!data) { // won't fire }
```

As Darin says, if you wrap up your response Json inside an object and then use that to assign to your `isClockOutTimeCompleted` variable.

I wouldn't have thought you'd want to perform a boolean evaluation of your return value if it's a true/false return type, wouldn't you just want to assign it to `isClockOutTimeCompleted` either way?

Comment: Unfortunetly `"false"` string is parsed to `false` correctly. Therefore `if (!data)` should trigger just fine. The problem is somewhere deeper.

Comment: I was thinking more that if you're method is intended to return t/f regarding the clocked timeout would you care if it was t/f when returned? wouldn't you just want to assign it irrespective?

Answer (score 0):

if ur posting data to a controller method always use

```
'type':'POST' in ur ajax call &
change the [HTTPget] attribute from ur controller method to [httpPost]
```

below is my sample code which works fine

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/temp',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'name':'surya'},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
             //here i'm getting the data which i have passed

            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("inside error")
            }
        });
```

and my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult temp(string name) {

            return Json(name);
        }
```

i'm getting back the data which i have passed in to the controller method via my jquery ajax..

may be u ought to change ur 'IsClockOutTimeCompleted' method where u are performing linq queries.just validate ur linq queries once..and also employeeId which ur passing into the controller is of type integer then instead of GUID as a parameter why dont u change the parameter type as int and see..

Regards